# Alert not shown in success Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php

I have an update button which is found in `<div class="section-center">` inside index.html

I have multiple scripts that are loaded:

- autosuggest.js
- populate_search_fields.js
- save_locations.js

In populate_search_fields.js I have the update-button code. The sql table is updated correctly but the success alert is not always shown. Why is this behaviour?

I tried to clear the cache and included a timeout.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".section-center").hide();

    // Function to populate Location Type and Source dropdowns
    function populateDropdowns() {
        // Populate Location Type Dropdown
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/fetch_location_types.php", // Create a PHP script to fetch location types
            success: function(response) {
                $("#location_type").html(response);
            }
        });

        // Populate Source Dropdown
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/fetch_sources.php", // Create a PHP script to fetch sources
            success: function(response) {
                $("#source").html(response);
            }
        });
    }

    $("#update-button").click(function() {
        var locationId = document.getElementById('location_id').value;
        var locationName = document.getElementById('location_name').value;
        var ASCIIName = document.getElementById('ASCII_name').value;
        var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
        var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude').value;
        var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
        var meaning = document.getElementById('meaning').value;
        var locationType = document.getElementById('location_type').value;
        var source = document.getElementById('source').value;
    
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/update_loc_data.php',
        data: {
            locationId: locationId,
            locationName: locationName,
            ASCIIName: ASCIIName,
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude,
            description: description,
            meaning: meaning,
            locationType: locationType,
            source: source
        },
        success: function (response) {
           // alert(response);
            alert('Data updated successfully!');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('Record not saved');
        }
    });
    
    });

    // $("#update-button").click(function() {
    
    
    //     // Send the data to a PHP script for database update
    // });

    
    $("#search-button").click(function() {
        document.getElementById('save-col').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('save-button').style.display = 'none';
        $('#save-button').prop("disabled", true);
        $('#location_name').val('');
        $('#ASCII_name').val('');
        $('#latitude').val('');
        $('#longitude').val('');
        $('#description').val('');
        $('#meaning').val('');

        
        populateDropdowns();
        var locationInputValue = $("#locationInput").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/fetch_locations.php",
            data: { query: locationInputValue },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    console.error(response.error);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(response);
                // Populate the input fields with data from the response

                $("#location_id").val(response.locId);
                $("#location_name").val(response.locName);
                $("#ASCII_name").val(response.asciiname);
                $("#latitude").val(response.latitude);
                $("#longitude").val(response.longitude);
                $("#description").val(response.description);
                $("#meaning").val(response.meaning);
                
                
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Set the selected option in the Location Type dropdown based on the response
                    $("#location_type option").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).text() === response.typeName) {
                            $(this).prop("selected", true);
                        }
                    });
                    
                    
                    // Set the selected option in the Source dropdown based on the response
                    $("#source option").each(function() {
                        if ($(this).text() === response.source) {     
                            $(this).prop("selected", true);
                        }
                    });
                }, 100); 
                          
                // $(".section-center input.form-control").prop("readonly", true);
                // $(".section-center input.form-control").addClass("readonly-input"); // Add a class for styling
              //  $(".section-center button.submit-btn").prop("disabled", true);
                // $("#location_type").prop("disabled", true);                    
                // $("#source").prop("disabled", true);
                document.getElementById('update-col').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('update-button').style.display = 'block';
                $('#update-button').prop("disabled", false);
                console.log('here');
                

                // Show the section-center
                $(".section-center").show();
            },
            error: function() {
                console.error("Error fetching data");
            }
        });
    });

    
});
```

and this is the php:

```
<?php
// Create a database connection
$conn = new mysqli("*", "root", "*", "geonamedb");

// Check for a successful connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . conn->connect_error);
}

// Check if the POST data for updating is set
if (isset($_POST["locationId"], $_POST["locationName"], $_POST["ASCIIName"], $_POST["latitude"], $_POST["longitude"], $_POST["description"], $_POST["meaning"], $_POST["locationType"], $_POST["source"])) {
    // Sanitize and validate data as needed

    // Get data from POST
    $locationId = $_POST["locationId"];
    $locationName = $_POST["locationName"];
    $ASCIIName = $_POST["ASCIIName"];
    $latitude = $_POST["latitude"];
    $longitude = $_POST["longitude"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $meaning = $_POST["meaning"];
    $locationType = $_POST["locationType"];
    $source = $_POST["source"];

    // Prepare an SQL UPDATE statement
    $sql = "UPDATE locations
            SET name = '$locationName',
                asciiname = '$ASCIIName',
                latitude = '$latitude',
                longitude = '$longitude',
                description = '$description',
                meaning = '$meaning',
                locationtype = '$locationType',
                sourceid = '$source'
            WHERE id = '$locationId'";

    // Execute the UPDATE statement
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        // Return a success message or any other response as needed
        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Data updated successfully'));
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the update fails
        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Error updating data'));
       
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Incomplete or missing data for updating'));
}

// Close the database connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: Never configure your web app to login to the database as `root`. Root can do whatever it likes, so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities this just leaves your database an open book for hackers. Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly. Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident.

Comment: `the success alert is not always shown. Why is this behaviour`....it's unclear, based on just the code. What debugging have you done? Use your browser's Developer Tools (primarily the Console and Network areas) to see what happens in cases where the alert is not shown. Perhaps there's a JS error or network error which occurs before the code can reach the `alert` command, for example.